# Ускорение программы Python

Tags: python, numpy

В одной биоинженерной компании по непонятной причине отказали все скрипты.

Так что генетики исследуют последовательности нуклеотидов вручную. Чтобы легче передавать информацию устно, они называют последовательность символов A, G, T, C «читаемой», если рядом ни с одной согласной нет другой согласной, а рядом ни с одной гласной — другой гласной, и предпочитают работать только с такими последовательностями.

Дано число N. Сколько различных читаемых последовательностей длины N существует? Так как ответ может быть очень большим, выведите остаток от его деления на 109 + 7.

Далее моя программа, она проходит только 23 теста из 40, ошибка TL. Кто знает как можно ее ускорить? Попробовал заменить деление и mod на другие операции, добавить функции, которые вроде как занимают меньше времени, но все равно по времени не проходит (1 сек)

N (1 ≤ N ≤ 10**9)

```
if int(N * 0.5) == N * 0.5:  
    print(int(int((3 ** int(N * 0.5)) * 2) % 1000000007))
else:
    print(int(int(4 * (3 ** int((N - 1) * 0.5))) % 1000000007))
```

Comment: А вы с матрицами уже закончили?

Comment: @MBo
С матрицами пока не закончил, решил отложить до лучших времен, попробовал написать программу по вашему способу, но я похоже что-то не так понял или где-то ошибся. Пока решил поискать решение для другой задачи, в которой тоже проблема со временем.

Comment: @MBo Она самая. Спасибо, большое)